# Django rest framework. If user exist return True, False if not

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

Need to preform simple check: If user exist return True, False if not.I am trying to solve thise problem using custom json answers, not sure it is the right way to deal with it. Please help me .

My serializer:

```
User = get_user_model()

Class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (User.USERNAME_FIELD, )
```

My views:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def UserViewSet(self, request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=User.USERNAME_FIELD)
            if User.DoesNotExist:
                json = {}
                json['message']= 'False'
                return Response(json)
            else:
                json = {}
                json['message']= 'True'
                return Response(json)
```

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do in this line `User.objects.get(username=User.USERNAME_FIELD)`.

Comment: Also, you can use `RetrieveAPIView` to decide if object exists or not. If `404` status code is returned, it means user does not exist. Otherwise `200` status code will be returned

Comment: trying get username with that line

Comment: But this query will always be `User.objects.get(username='field_name')`. How will this retrieve intended unique user?

Comment: the thing is i should get True or False insetead of 404 or 200 exceptions.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using `UserViewSet` and `UserSerializer`, you can just use  [APIView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/) for that.

```
class UserExistsView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # use this if username is in url kwargs
        username = self.kwargs.get('username') 

        # use this if username is being sent as a query parameter
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username')  

        try:
            user = User.objects.get(username=username) # retrieve the user using username
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(data={'message':False}) # return false as user does not exist
        else:
            return Response(data={'message':True}) # Otherwise, return True
```

Comment: how in this case query should look like? User.objects.get(self.kwargs['username']) ?

Comment: How are you sending the `username` of a particular user? Is it in url `kwargs` or as a query parameter?

Comment: regular i use next contruction to return some filtered data - 
def get_queryset(self):
    user = self.kwargs['username']
    return User.objects.filter[username=user]

Comment: Updated the ans with 2 options to get the `username` and then perform a lookup based on it.

Comment: I this is very old...but i tried this but i am getting empty response using apisauce. i have asked the question here.Kindly assist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624712/drf-apiview-returns-empty-data-object-when-using-apisauce-but-not-on-browser-vie?noredirect=1#comment114267644_64624712