# DRF APIView returns empty data object when using apisauce but not on browser view

Tags: reactjs, react-native, django-rest-framework

I am trying to query a model to check if an object exists or not using the following `APIview` function. Unfortunately i am not able to receive any response object in react native apisauce get function as shown below

apisauce function

```
const checkIfUserExists = (email) =>
  client.get("/account/user-exists/?email=" + email);
```

APIView class

```
class UserExistsView(APIView):

    """Checks if user exists or not"""

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        username = self.request.GET['email']

        try:
           
            user = models.UserProfile.objects.get(email=username)
        except models.UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
           
            return Response(data={'message': False})
        else:
            return Response(data={'message': True})
```

**Results from the browser**
[image]
What am i doing wrong here?

Print result on shell `<Response status_code=200, "text/html; charset=utf-8">`

Comment: Could you tell what are you exactly getting in the browser. Also, why are you returning that data inside a list? Any specific requirement for that?

Comment: I have added more info to the question.I added the list just to test. I have removed

Comment: Doesn't seem to have any problem with the DRF view. Can you also give entire checkIfUserExists function. i dont see any .then() here.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it simplier:

```
class UserExistsView(APIView):
    """Checks if user exists or not"""

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        
        email = self.request.GET['email']
        user_exists = models.UserProfile.objects.filter(email=email).exists()

        return Response(
            data={'message': user_exists}
        )
```

If you create a QuerySet and then call `.exists()`, Django will call the SQL function checking only if the object is in the database, but it will not query it, which is much faster and desired in your call from JS.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a class base component, You could modify your function like below, track the user existence in state. I don't see any errors in your server-side code. but in your javascript code you didn't handle the promise.

```
checkUserExists= (email) => {
    client.get("/account/user-exists/?email=" + email)
    .then(response=>{
     this.setState({isUserExists : response.data.messgae})
    )
}
```